# How do you put conditionals in an RPM spec file for %install and %file macros?

Tags: centos, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I only want files copied into an RPM spec file under a certain condition like:

```
%install 
if [ %{test}=="true" ]; 
then
    cp %{topdirectory}/file1.txt $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/home/user1
fi

%files
if [ %{test}=="true" ]; 
then
   %attr(0644, user1,user1) /home/user1/file1.txt
fi
```

When I execute rpmbuild I pass in a flag to define what "test" is, like:

```
rpmbuild --define="test true" --bb --quiet myspecfile.spec
```

However, I get an error message that looks like:

```
error: File must begin with "/": if
error: File must begin with "/": [
error: File must begin with "/": false=="true"
error: File must begin with "/": ]; 
error: File must begin with "/": then
error: File must begin with "/": fi
```

I'm not really sure what this error message means, but it clearly does not like me putting an if statement near the %files macro or the %install macro.  How do I change my if statement to make rpmbuild happy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spec has its own syntax for conditionals, you need to use something like this:

```
%if %{test} == "true"
%attr(0644, user1,user1) /home/user1/file1.txt
%endif
```

You can read more about spec syntax [here](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/spec.html).